# One to Many relationships in EF Core 3.0 returning Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to create a one to many relationships in EF Core 3.0 where Users can have multiple games but when I pull up the route for a user in postman the Games field is returning null. How do this properly? Here's my model.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Domain
{
    public class User
    {
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public string UserName { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public List<Game> Games {get; set;}
    }

   public class Game
   {
       public int GameId {get; set;}
       public string GameName { get; set; }
       public int UserId {get; set;}
       public User User {get; set;}
   }
}
```

Comment: you never show code to return data. i post answer anyway in case you might not use it.

Answer (score 1):

use Include linq

```
context.User.Include(x => x.Games);
```